# How to spread a dataset in R keeping the name of each column

Tags: r

I have a dataset with columns date, hour, A, B , C and I want to spread the columns by hour and to get 24 columns for each of A B C. For example this is the outcome I want :

date   A.1  A.2   A.3  .... A.24  B.1  B.2 ....  B.24  C.1  C.2 .... C24

I used the date, hour, A  and tried this code: spread (hour, A) but it gives me as columns names the hour values and not the A.1 A.2. Besides I cannot manage this by multiple columns. maybe pivot_wider?

I'm a beginner so I hope that I explained it well. Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any data, so I just made some up

```
df=data.frame(
  "Date"=rep(as.Date(paste0("2021-04-0",1:3)),each=24),
  "Hour"=rep(0:23,times=3),
  "A"=1:(24*3),
  "B"=(1:(24*3))*2,
  "C"=(1:(24*3))*3
)

library(reshape2)
df2=melt(df,c("Date","Hour"),c("A","B","C"))
dcast(data=df2,Date~variable+Hour)

        Date A_0 A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4 A_5 A_6 A_7 A_8 A_9 A_10 A_11 A_12 A_13 A_14 A_15 A_16 A_17 A_18
1 2021-04-01   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
2 2021-04-02  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43
3 2021-04-03  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67
  A_19 A_20 A_21 A_22 A_23 B_0 B_1 B_2 B_3 B_4 B_5 B_6 B_7 B_8 B_9 B_10 B_11 B_12 B_13 B_14 B_15
1   20   21   22   23   24   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20   22   24   26   28   30   32
2   44   45   46   47   48  50  52  54  56  58  60  62  64  66  68   70   72   74   76   78   80
3   68   69   70   71   72  98 100 102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116  118  120  122  124  126  128
  B_16 B_17 B_18 B_19 B_20 B_21 B_22 B_23 C_0 C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4 C_5 C_6 C_7 C_8 C_9 C_10 C_11 C_12
1   34   36   38   40   42   44   46   48   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30   33   36   39
2   82   84   86   88   90   92   94   96  75  78  81  84  87  90  93  96  99 102  105  108  111
3  130  132  134  136  138  140  142  144 147 150 153 156 159 162 165 168 171 174  177  180  183
  C_13 C_14 C_15 C_16 C_17 C_18 C_19 C_20 C_21 C_22 C_23
1   42   45   48   51   54   57   60   63   66   69   72
2  114  117  120  123  126  129  132  135  138  141  144
3  186  189  192  195  198  201  204  207  210  213  216
```